# Text box which populates database value needs to reset when clicks submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a text box which populates from database value.

```
<form id="manageSalesForm" name="manageSalesForm" method="post" action="<?php echo BASE_URL?>includes/functions/sales_functions.php">

<input name="txtSubTotal" type="text" id="txtSubTotal" size="15" value="<?php 
                                            $sql=mysqli_query($connection,'select sum(amount) from sales_temp');
                                            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
                                            echo $row[0];
                                            ?>"/>
```

I need to reset this, once submit button is clicked. (Moreover, when I clicked the button second time, it clears the text box.

```
<input type="submit" name="btnProceed" id="btnProceed" value="PROCEED" onclick="document.getElementById('txtSubTotal').value = '';"/>
```

**Proceed button query**

```
<?php

//Start the Session
       if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
       { 
           session_start(); 
       } 

include ("/../../pages/sales.php");
include("/../../dbutil.php");

if(isset($_POST['listCustomer'])){ $customer = $_POST['listCustomer'];}
if(isset($_POST['staff'])){ $user = $_POST['staff']; }
if(isset($_POST['txtReceiptNo'])){ $receipt_no = $_POST['txtReceiptNo']; } 
if(isset($_POST['txtSubTotal'])){ $subTotal = $_POST['txtSubTotal']; } 

if(isset($_POST['btnProceed'])){


$result=mysqli_query($connection, 
"INSERT INTO sales(cus_id,item_id,stock_id,receipt_no,qty,unit_price,amount,user_id,purchase_id) 
SELECT C.cus_id, I.item_id, S.stock_id, $receipt_no, ST.qty, ST.unit_price, ST.amount, U.id, P.purchase_id 
FROM customers C, items I, stock S, sales_temp ST, users U, purchase_items P 
WHERE ST.staff='$user' 
AND C.customer_name='$customer' 
AND I.item_name=ST.item_name 
AND S.stock_code=ST.stock_code 
AND ST.purchase_id=P.purchase_id");


//Update available qty from purchase_items relevant only to the logged in user(sales_temp table may have records from multiple users)
$resultUpdate=mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE purchase_items P INNER JOIN sales_temp ST ON (P.purchase_id = ST.purchase_id) SET P.avail_qty = (P.avail_qty - ST.qty) WHERE ST.staff='$user'");

//Delete records relevant only to current user. Here 'WHERE' clause use to prevent deleting other user's records.
$resultDelete=mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM sales_temp WHERE staff='$user'");


if (!$result) {
  printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
}

// use exec() because no results are returned
if ($result) {

/*echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
 'salesAddSuccess();',
'</script>';*/
}
else
{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
 'salesAddFail();',
'</script>';
}}
?>
```

Code of button `onclick` for displaying the **Sub Total**, `showSubTotal()`

```
<button type="button" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" onclick="submitdata(); check_qty(); showSubTotal();">ADD</button>
```

This code not works. Please help me.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: No, not for this.

Comment: reset with the new value which u inserted

Comment: is the php code being called onclick of the button?and is it present in the same page as the html and the js?

Comment: First of all, in the javascript function on your submit button you should escape the double quotes or use single quotes: `onclick="document.getElementById('txtSubTotal').value = '';"`  . Second, do you want to reset the value in the `txtSubTotal` before submitting the form?

Comment: @moni_draguI edited the code as your first suggestion. secondly, I want to reset the text box after click the submit button.

Comment: @GraveyardQueen Yes, php code for **Sub Total** is being called onclick of another button. (Added the code under **PHP code of button onclick for displaying the Sub Total `showSubTotal()`**).

Comment: no i meant the proceed button php code that is where is that been called?

Comment: It is added under **Proceed button query** above. It is been called `sales_functions.php`, which also added on my post.

Comment: So that means onclick of the button your field is supposed to be reset and your form gets submitted calling the php code isn't it?

Comment: yes form submission should be done, calling the php code and the text box should be reset.

Comment: "PHP code of button `onclick` for displaying the Sub Total, `showSubTotal()`."   This can not be PHP code, it is/must be javascript code.

Comment: It was by mistake, corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, added the do_onload(id) to calculate the total on loadComplete event which is triggered after each refresh (also after delete)

```
function do_onload(id)
{
//alert('Simulating, data on load event')

var s = $("#list").jqGrid('getCol', 'amount', false, 'sum');
jQuery("#txtSubTotal").val(s);
}
```

And changed the phpgrid code accordingly.

```
$opt["loadComplete"] = "function(ids) { do_onload(ids); }";
$grid->set_options($opt);
```